# como obter o tempo minimo médio e máximo de um timeseries com pandas, baseado em uma coluna onde o valor é boleano?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, timestamp

estou analisando uma timeseries retornada com pandas ex:

```
index----valor------timestamp <br>
----0  -------0--------       2019-04-23 16:14:34.142540+00:00<br>
----1  -------0--------       2019-04-23 16:15:34.142540+00:00<br>
----2  -------1--------       2019-04-23 16:16:34.142540+00:00<br>
----3  -------0--------       2019-04-23 16:17:34.142540+00:00<br>
----4  -------1--------       2019-04-23 16:18:34.142540+00:00<br>
----5  -------1--------       2019-04-23 16:19:34.142540+00:00<br>
----6  -------0--------       2019-04-23 16:20:34.142540+00:00<br>
.<br>.<br>.<br>
```

Baseado nesses dados preciso calcular os tempo total  que o valor esteve em '0' e em '1',  
 O mímino seria o menor tempo que o valor mantevesse em 0 e em 1, 
O máximo seria o maior tempo que o valor mantevesse em 0 e em 1 .

e a média dos tempos...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partindo de que a sua coluna `timestamp` são datas. Se não forem, pode transformá-las assim: `df['timestamp'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`

Uma solução é criar outro Data Frame `df_intervalos`, com as colunas `data_fim, data_inicio, valor` e percorrer o dataframe original linha a linha, vendo quando a sequência muda e preenchendo o `df_intervalos`.

Ele pode ser preenchido assim:

```
# crio o df_intervalos 
df_intervalos =  pd.DataFrame(data = {'data_inicio':[], 'data_fim':[], 'valor':[]})

data_inicio = df['timestamp'].values[0]
data_fim = df['timestamp'].values[0]
sequencia = df['valor'].values[0]

for index, linha in df[1:].iterrows(): # percorro linha a linha
    if linha['valor'] != sequencia: # Se o valor for diferente, encerra a sequencia
        df_intervalos = df_intervalos.append({'data_inicio' : data_inicio,
                                              'data_fim' : data_fim,
                                              'valor': sequencia} , ignore_index=True)
        data_inicio = linha['timestamp']
        sequencia = linha['valor']

    data_fim = linha['timestamp']

# Adiciona a ultima sequência
df_intervalos = df_intervalos.append({'data_inicio' : data_inicio,
                                              'data_fim' : data_fim,
                                              'valor': sequencia} , ignore_index=True)
```

Depois tiramos o tempo de cada sequencia subtraindo as datas de inicio e fim de cada sequência:

`df_intervalos['tempo_calculado'] = (df_intervalos['data_fim'] - df_intervalos['data_inicio'])`

O resultado é algo como:

```
                    data_fim                   data_inicio   valor   tempo_calculado
0 2019-04-23 16:15:34.142540    2019-04-23 16:14:34.142540    0.0        00:01:00
1 2019-04-23 16:16:34.142540    2019-04-23 16:16:34.142540    1.0        00:00:00
2 2019-04-23 16:17:34.142540    2019-04-23 16:17:34.142540    0.0        00:00:00
3 2019-04-23 16:19:34.142540    2019-04-23 16:18:34.142540    1.0        00:01:00
4 2019-04-23 16:20:34.142540    2019-04-23 16:20:34.142540    0.0        00:00:00
```

Agora, para saber o valor máximo, mínimo e a média da duração da sequência `1`, por exemplo:

```
>>> df_intervalos[df_intervalos['valor']==1]['tempo_calculado'].max()
    Timedelta('0 days 00:01:00')

>>> df_intervalos[df_intervalos['valor']==1]['tempo_calculado'].min()
    Timedelta('0 days 00:00:00')

>>> df_intervalos[df_intervalos['valor']==1]['tempo_calculado'].mean()
    Timedelta('0 days 00:00:30')
```

Ou ainda se quiser a linha toda:

```
>>> df_intervalos[df_intervalos['valor']==1][df_intervalos['tempo_calculado'] ==df_intervalos['tempo_calculado'].max()]

                    data_fim                   data_inicio   valor   tempo_calculado
3 2019-04-23 16:19:34.142540    2019-04-23 16:18:34.142540    1.0        00:01:00
```

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado por seu empenho em responder com tanta qualidade..  sua abordagem funcionou muito bem para mim, sobretudo no sentido gerar outro dataframe com os valores que eu precisava... dessa forma, através de algums ajustes e necessaria modelagem eu resolvi meu problema. Mais uma vez Obrigado !